# Inconsistent boolean behavior

Tags: mesh, modifiers

Blender 2.72  Boolean operations with the primitive forms give expected results.  Trying to use a e.g. cube to remove the tabs from a hand by difference to leave the hand doesn't give the expected result.   Trying to use the cube in the same position with an intersection does not result in the removed tab.
One of the operations looks like a union.
Any suggestions?
If you want more info, please tell me how to obtain it.  I'm not having a good day with Blender. 
[image: the tabs on the back of the hand are my targets]

Comment: please post images that show the issue, or upload the blend file for others to inspect it.

Comment: This is the Cyborg Beast hand used by eNABLE..  I imported the stl files into Blender.  If you need the stl files, they are available on the eNABLE website.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you aren't using a recent version of Blender? like 2.74 currently?

Comment: I think Blender is an awesome program with quirks which are minimally documented.  If I were using Blender every day or every week, I'd have much more reason to have the latest version and live on the bleeding edge of reading StackExchange every day.  Call me a Luddite, but Blender is a little like Windows: Just let me learn to use what I have before giving me a new set of features/quirks/bugs.

Answer (score 1):

I just got consistent behavior (after 2 days) by selecting both pieces, going to edit, and recalculating the normals to be outside, then back to object and performing the operation.
Do you need a picture for that?